# Custom JS/CSS select alternative without jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

I am trying to make a custom select just like [this](https://lcdsantos.github.io/jQuery-Selectric/demo.html), but without jquery (I just dont want to import a whole new library for one single thing). I made it until [this](http://bit.ly/1lHofKH), but I dont know how I can make the selection with regular JS. How can I select something from the list?

Comment: Define *select*. what should happen when you *select*..?

Comment: Well, listen to `#options` click. Define which option was clicked and treat its html as a value.

Comment: I dont understand why do you want change it. It looks like vanila select and no new feature added(filter by text)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to show the selected item in the dropdown,

You need to wrap the text to be displayed inside a `<span>` as follows

```
<div class="label"><span>Select Element</span><b class="button">▾</b>
</div>
```

Then you can change it's `innterHTML` to display the selected item using the following js:

```
var dd = document.querySelector('.label span');
var options = document.querySelectorAll('div.hidden ul li');
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    options[i].onclick = select;
}

function show() {
 var selectbox = document.getElementById("options");
 if (selectbox.className == "hidden") {
   selectbox.setAttribute("class", "visible");
 } else {
        selectbox.setAttribute("class", "hidden");
 }
}

function select() {
 dd.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rWU5t/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Listen to clicks on your `div#options`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/rWU5t/4/)

```
function choose(ev, el) {
    var options = el, target = ev.target,
        value = ev.target.innerHTML;

    options.setAttribute('class', 'hidden');
    options.parentElement.querySelector('.label').innerHTML = value;
}

<div id="options" class="hidden" onclick='choose (event, this);'>
```

Side notes. I don't recommend to use inline handlers. Use `addEventListener` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an onclick handler of your `li` elements. Either in HTML, or in JS by looping through children of `div` container with `li` elements http://jsfiddle.net/rWU5t/2/

If you want fancy item highlights on mouse hover, you also need to define `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` handlers.